# Remove words in a cell that are already in another cell

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have Business names in column A and descriptions in Column B. this descriptions included business names also. Example:

```
Column A: McLain Homes
Column B: McLain Homes Est in 1990 McLain ideally suited to indoor/outdoor lifestyle.
```

Now I want to remove the business names from  description. In this example, remove McLain Homes from column B.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Probably you can work with `SUBSTITUTE` function, but without seeing your data I can't tell more.

Comment: Column A :McLain Homes. Column B: McLain Homes Est in 1990 McLain ideally suited to indoor/outdoor lifestyle. I want to remove McLain Homes from column B. Is this clear?

Answer (score 2):

The substitute function should work

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"")
```